# RewriteCond to exclude a directory IIS

Tags: iis, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the following rules in my `.htaccess`file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/admin/
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|swf|css|html|htm|php|rar|xml|ani|cur|mp3|mp4|flv|tpl|inc)$ /admin/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/admin/
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|swf|css|html|htm|php|rar|xml|ani|cur|mp3|mp4|flv|tpl|inc|doc|exe|zip)$ index.php [L,NC]
```

I want change it for IIs,how to change?

```
[ISAPI_Rewrite]
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/admin/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^[\w/\%]*(?:\.(?!(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|swf|css|html|htm|php|rar|xml|ani|cur|mp3|mp4|flv|tpl|inc|doc|exe|zip|txt)$)[\w\%]*$)? /index.php [I]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/admin/.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^[\w/\%]*(?:\.(?!(?:js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|png|swf|css|html|htm|php|rar|xml|ani|cur|mp3|mp4|flv|tpl|inc|doc|exe|zip|txt)$)[\w\%]*$)? /admin/index.php [I]
```

Comment: I changed the formatting of your post to make it easier to read. Still it's not clear, what you're asking: have you tried the second code with `ISAPI_Rewrite` and it didn't work? (What was the error in this case). Or do you want to know, if there's a better approach with IIS? You might need to clarify your question to get an answer here on SO.

Comment: I think he is asking the syntactical differences between mod_rewrite on Apache and ISAPI Rewrite on Windows for his given set of rules.